# shell script , how to find a combination of ! and *

Tags: regex, bash

I wrote this script to find a string with only `*` and `!`
However, it can not find any string consists only `*`
I couldn't figure out what's wrong with my regular expression, Could someone please help? Thank you!

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=('!!' '!' '*' '*!' '**' '**!' '!*!' '***' 'bla!' )
echo  star is "${arr[2]}"

for i in ${arr[@]}; do if [[ "$i" == [\!\*]* ]] ; then echo match "$i"; fi; done
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do if [[ "$i" =~ "^[\!\*]*$" ]] ; then echo match "$i"; fi; done
```

Edit:(for Dennis)

```
$ for i in "${arr[@]}"; do if [[ "$i" =~ "^[\!\*]*$" ]] ; then echo match "$i"; fi; done
match !!
match !
match *
match *!
match **
match **!
match !*!
match ***

$ for i in "${arr[@]}"; do if [[ "$i" =~ ^[\!\*]*$ ]] ; then echo match "$i"; fi; done
match !!
match !
match *
match *!
match **
match **!
match !*!
match ***
```

Comment: Quoting the right hand side of a `=~` match makes it a literal string instead of a regex. Drop that set of quotes.

Comment: From the [Conditional Constructs](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC21) section of the manual: "Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a string."

Comment: @dennis, well i really don't understand that part, since I get the same results whether or not I put the quotes.

Comment: When I use the OP's array and your command in Bash 4, I get no output at all unless I `shopt -s compat31`.

Comment: Do `shopt -p compat31`. If the output says "shopt -s compat31" then you have this option turned on which affects this particular functionality. Since the default behavior was changed between Bash 3.1 and 3.2 (and `=~` was introduced in 3.0), it is preferable to have this option *off*. See the [COMPAT](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/COMPAT) file.

Comment: I get no output using your command with the quoted regex in Bash 3.2 on Cygwin, Bash 3.2, 4.0, 4.1 or 4.2 or ksh93t+ in Ubuntu. I do get output in Bash if I `shopt -s compat31` or if I remove the quotes or if I run it in zsh. I assume I would also get output if I ran it in *actual* Bash 3.1. Otherwise *no repro*.

Comment: @Dennis, sorry, I guess I am not being specific. My bash version is 4.0.33.

Comment: When I said "4.0" I also meant "4.0.33" (to be more specific: 4.0.33(1)-release. What happens if you do `[[ a =~ "." ]] && echo match || echo no`?

Comment: @Dennis, its says "match" for both quoted and unquoted.

Comment: Try `[[ $BASH_VERSION =~ "4\.0" ]] && echo yes || echo no`

Comment: I found out that if you're on Fedora, this was a bug that was fixed in the bash-4.1.2-1 package.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to quote your array in the `for` statement:

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do if [[ "$i" == [*!]* ]] ; then echo match "$i"; fi; done
```

If you put the exclamation point second, you don't need to escape it (the asterisk doesn't need escaping in any case).

By the way, that's not a regular expression. It's a shell globbing expression.